# Neither pendant light or ceiling box has loose wires

Tags: lighting, ceiling, installation

So I'll preface with this is the first time I've ever tried to install a light. I brought several pendant lamps from Ikea, on the end of the wires is a plastic box where i should be able to connect the wires from the ceiling to (assuming the ceiling had loose wires).

[image: Plastic box around lamp wires]

But in the ceiling box, only the ground wire is lose (well covered in plaster), the others have their own plastic box connector. And they boxes don't fit each other. The ceiling one has two screws to attach the wires to (presumably assuming the lamp would have loose wires).

[image: ceiling fixture]

So whats the best option here? Cut the plastic connector off of the lamp wires? Though i have another lamp that has a thicker cord which would be a lot harder to cut. Maybe get some wire and connect it between the boxes? I cant do anything to the ceiling box as its a rented accommodation.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: The Netherlands.

Comment: I would get an old work box cut an opening for the box and mount that in the ceiling. Our codes on the other side of the pond require boxes where the connections are made.